# Can't modify Pandas DataFrame while iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop

My question is about the FOR loop below and it's something I see being used by prominent data scientists on Kaggle.  However it doesn't seem to work for me.

Python 3.66.
Pandas 0.23.4

## setup

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3, 1], 'time':['2017-04-17 22:23:22', '2018-05-22 14:20:00', '2017-01-09 08:02:14']})
test = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3, 1], 'time':['2017-04-17 22:23:22', '2018-05-22 14:20:00', '2017-01-09 08:02:14']})
train

>>>         id  time  
>>>   0     2   2017-04-17 22:23:22
>>>   1     3   2018-05-22 14:20:00
>>>   2     1   2017-01-09 08:02:14
```

## Sort it (this works)

```
train.sort_values('time', ascending=True)

>>>     id  time
>>> 2   1   2017-01-09 08:02:14
>>> 0   2   2017-04-17 22:23:22
>>> 1   3   2018-05-22 14:20:00
```

## Sort it in a FOR loop - why does this not work?

```
for data in [train, test]:
    data = data.sort_values('time', ascending=True)
train

>>>     id  time
>>> 0   2   2017-04-17 22:23:22
>>> 1   3   2018-05-22 14:20:00
>>> 2   1   2017-01-09 08:02:14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sort it in a FOR loop - why does this not work?

Because your `for` loop doesn't bind your newly defined variable `data` to the objects within your `[train, test]`. You are redefining `data` within each loop without changing `train` or `test`.

Instead, you can use sequence unpacking:

```
train, test = (df.sort_values('time') for df in (train, test))
```

Or, use `enumerate` in a `for` loop:

```
data = [train, test]
for idx, df in enumerate(data):
    data[idx] = df.sort_values('time')
```

Then refer to your dataframes via index, i.e. `data[0]`, `data[1]`.

Or, use a dictionary and iterate items:

```
data = {'train': train, 'test': test}

for key, df in d.items():
    data[key] = df.sort_values('time')
```

Then refer to your dataframes via key, i.e. `data['train']`, `data['test']`.

Comment: Okay so it seems this works only on series but not on dataframes.  E.g. this works:

```for data in [train, test]:
    data['time'] = 5```

Comment: jpp, I tried your 3 proposed solutions.  Only the first method actually sorts the data in train.  The other 2 methods don't.

Comment: @ihopethiswillfi, You have to understand how to use the second and third solutions. Refer to dataframes thenceforth as `data[0] / data[1]` in the first case, or `data['train'] / data['test']` in the second case.

Comment: Oh yea that makes sense.  Thanks.
Any idea why updating the Series works, but updating the DataFrame does not?  Or I can also create a new question.

Comment: @ihopethiswillfi, Sorry, not sure what you mean by "updating the Series".

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way, just use inplace=True parameter for sorting

```
>>> train = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3, 1], 'time':['2017-04-17 22:23:22', '2018-05-22 14:20:00', '2017-01-09 08:02:14']})
>>> test = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 3, 1], 'time':['2017-04-17 22:23:22', '2018-05-22 14:20:00', '2017-01-09 08:02:14']})
>>> for data in [train, test]:
     data.sort_values('time', ascending=True, inplace=True)

>>> test
   id                 time
2   1  2017-01-09 08:02:14
0   2  2017-04-17 22:23:22
1   3  2018-05-22 14:20:00
>>> train
   id                 time
2   1  2017-01-09 08:02:14
0   2  2017-04-17 22:23:22
1   3  2018-05-22 14:20:00
```

If you want the index to update again just add reset_indext()

```
data.sort_values('time', ascending=True, inplace=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: Correct.  Unfortunately inplace is going to be deprecated.  Source: recent video by one of the main Pandas developers.  Sorry I forgot the link and his name.